# Fetch some records with while loop and some without loop

Tags: php, web, pdo

I want to show some records with while loops and some without loops. But a while loop ignores the first record and show other records.

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['patient_no'])) {
                $patient_id = $_SESSION['patient_no'];
                $sql = $db->prepare("select * from patient_record JOIN medicine_potency ON  reference_no=:reference_id and patient_code=:reference_no");
                if (!$sql) {
                    echo $sql->errorInfo();
                } else {
                    $sql->bindParam('reference_id', $patient_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $sql->bindParam('reference_no', $patient_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $sql->execute();
                    $sql->bindColumn('code', $id);
                    $sql->bindColumn('reference_no', $reference_no);
                    $sql->bindColumn('patient_name', $patient_name);
                    $sql->bindColumn('father_name', $father_name);
 if ($sql->columnCount() > 0) {
                     $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                            ?>
                        <tr bgcolor=" #005A04"><td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; color:#CCFFBB">Personal Information</td></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Reference No</td>
                                <td><?php echo $reference_no; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>Patient Name</td>
                                <td><?php echo $patient_name; ?></td>
                        </tr><?php while ($sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                           ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $medicine; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $potency; ?></td>
                            </tr>
```

Comment: everytime you do a $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); a record is read. Your first fetch is outside the while

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: You could reverse the while-loop to a do-while loop, so the first iteration it will use your first fetch. that only works if you have a single fetch before the loop obviously.

But I'm not sure what the point is in your case you do the same fetch before the loop, so why are you even needing it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OFFSET` syntax in your MYSQL statement:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("select * from patient_record JOIN medicine_potency ON  reference_no=:reference_id and patient_code=:reference_no OFFSET 1");
```

This will skip the first result, and move on.